# Add CSS in a function

Tags: javascript, css, function

I got my function to display my site to full screen :

```
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    }
  }
```

that I associate with a button image and it worked !

But when I move my cursor over it, the cursor remains in "default" version so I would like it to become "pointer" to give the effect of a button : "cursor: pointer;" and I don't manage to enter my css in the function to make it work.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in JavaScript and not just in CSS?

Comment: Why you dont add css with cursor pointer for this button?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to add the CSS in that function? Just style the image. Better yet, use a real button (with an image inside it) instead of a plain image. Buttons work well with screen readers and other assistive technology as well as non-mouse input in general.

Comment: @NickPantelidis how ?

Comment: button { cursor: pointer; } . It is very simple or image { cursor: pointer; } depending on what you have.

Comment: Hey @puppyda can you show some part of your HTML, so that i could give you answer.

Comment: Hello @SagunGautam, it's with a builder so there is no other html part only this than I linked to an image

Comment: document.getElementById("imageButton").style.cursor = "pointer"; if you want pure Javascript

Comment: @NickPantelidis I don't especially want pure javascript but I really don't know anything about it so I don't know how to put some css without it breaking my function (I've been trying for 2 hours but it never worked)

Comment: @puppyda: *"so there is no other html part"* - If there's *no HTML* at all then the question is entirely unclear, what UI is this JavaScript code interacting with?  If there *is* HTML then regardless of what tool you use to build that HTML it's going to be an important step for you to *look at* that HTML, because that's what your JavaScript and/or CSS sees.  Examining the HTML/CSS/JavaScript in a web application is a critical part of web development.

Comment: @puppyda: *"how to put some css without it breaking my function"* - What did you try that affected that function in any way?  CSS is entirely separate from JavaScript.  If you're not familiar with how to use CSS at all then it sounds like an introductory tutorial on HTML/CSS would be a great place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically what you can do is

```css
button{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello there</button>
```

You can also add a class to your button

```css
.btn{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Hello there</button>
```

Comment: You don't need at all to add :hover

Comment: Thank you it worked !
I wasn't know I have to inject code before to add class

Answer (score 2):

If you can add class to your button `button` then just add the CSS below to get pointer when you hover over a button.

```
.button:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure css

```css
#fullscreen {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullscreen"></div>
```

or with pure Javascript

```js
document.getElementById("fullscreen").style.cursor = "pointer";
```

```css
#fullscreen {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullscreen"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll be the first to admit that my CSS is not amazing by any means but if you were to add a class to the actual button itself in the HTML portion of your page and add the property `cursor: pointer` to that class' attributes, I believe that should do the trick? I would have rather left this as a comment instead of an answer but I'm not reputable enough for a comment yet haha

Comment: I realize you don't have the rep yet to leave comments, but that shouldn't be a reason to leave an answer that really should be a comment. Work on posting quality answers until you get the rep to comment.

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks for the feedback Scott.

Comment: Hello @DarrenWoodson,
first of all thank you for your help but it's a builder so I don't have access to the html.
Only link that to the picture : https://ibb.co/g3Z0SbV